# How to show only uniq tags in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, erb, words, uniq

I have the code below. I would like to make that only one tag print to view for every question. But now it prints two and more times. I know why. But I don't know how to fix it. 
I used uniq for first line.
But I gues it is not very beautiful.

```
<% question.tags.each do |tag| %>
 <div class="question-text micro_hashtag">
    <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(name: tag.name) %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: _"But I gues(s) it is not very beautiful."_ - why do you think so?

Comment: _"...I would like to make that only one tag print...I used uniq for first line..."_ - Do you want to print only one tag per question OR print all unique tags for each question?

Comment: I would like to print all uniq tags after every question

Comment: In that case, this problem should actually be handled at model level. You should not be able to create tags with duplicate names associated to a question. Add some validation there.

Comment: at model no proble, I have there `validates :name, uniqueness: true`
And in DB all tags are uniq.

Comment: Then, how come a question has duplicate tags above?

Comment: Because when scan each. And for example I have a question: "hi, #what are #you doing?'
It will be scan first time two hashtags #what and #you. Then it will scan each method again becase question has 2 hastags. And again will print #what and #you